# While downloading pdf file from another server forward slash is get replaced with underscore

Tags: php, pdf, download

I am trying to download pdf file from my server. while downloading file it replaces forward slash(/) with underscore and file path become like this(`127.0.0.1_file_upload_demoform1.pdf`), because of that not able to download file.

here is code.

```
header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
$download_path = "127.0.0.1/file_upload/demoform1.pdf";
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$download_path);
readfile('downloads/'.$download_path);
```

Can anyone suggest what is issue in it.

Comment: Do you mean the `$download_path` variable content changes? Or do you mean the value of the Content-Disposition filename parameter changes when transmitted to your client?

Comment: @mkl `$download_path` variable content changes its value at time of downloading.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer.
I was trying to download the pdf file from another server. which does not allow me directly download from that location.

Here is my solution.

```
$content = file_get_contents('http://127.0.0.1/file_upload/demoform1.pdf');
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=demoform1.pdf');
echo $content;
```